# gamma correction in matlab

Tags: matlab, gamma

currently i am working on my demosiac converter project which convert RAW images , one step of converting image is the gamma correction .

this is my gamma correction function in matlab :

```
function [res] = gamma_correct(I, value)

% res = gamma_correct(I, value)
%
% This function performs gamma correction
% on image 'I' where 'value' is the gamma

res = I;


X = 255 * (I/255).^(1/value);
imshow(X);

end
```

this function runs without errors but finally it gives me a wrong output

[this is a screenshot of the output i get](http://postimg.org/image/rn6s8rvkv/)

any help ?

Comment: I can't quite tell what I'm looking at. ;) The image is pretty small. What's wrong with it? Is is over-saturated?

Comment: and this is the problem as i expect something like this  [link](http://postimg.org/image/7ttoj985l/)

Comment: I can't say I know why the image changed size. Try using `I = double(I);` before you do any calculations on the image though. Doing division with integers will floor the result, to zero if the image is `uint8` type.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct image into your function?  What where are you pulling the data to get the good and bad outputs you show?

Comment: actually this is the image i want to apply the function on [link](http://postimg.org/image/7ttoj985l/)  and this the output i get after applying the function [link](http://postimg.org/image/rn6s8rvkv/)